# Delete paragraph containing string in python

Tags: python

I have a file that contains blocks of information beginning and ending with the same phrase:

```
# Info block
Info line 1
Info line 2
Internal problem
ENDOFPARAMETERPOINT
```

I am trying to write a python code that deletes the entire block beginning with # Info block and ending with ENDOFPARAMETERPOINT once it detects the phrase Internal problem.

```
finds = '# Info block\nInfo line 1\nInfo line 2\nInternal problem\nENDOFPARAMETERPOINT'

with open(filename,"r+") as fp:
     pattern = re.compile(r'[,\s]+' + re.escape(finds) + r'[\s]+')
     textdata = fp.read()
     line = re.sub(pattern,'',textdata)
     fp.seek(0)
     fp.write(line)
```

This code only works for one line but not the entire paragraph. Any suggestions are appreciated.

EDIT:

The code that works now is:

```
with open(filename,"r+") as fp:
     pattern = re.compile(re.escape(finds))
     textdata = fp.read()
     line = re.sub(pattern,'',textdata)
     fp.seek(0)
     fp.write(line)
     fp.truncate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just use `pattern = re.compile(re.escape(finds))`?

Comment: Thanks @formicaman. That alone did not solve the issue, I had to add fp.truncate() at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two lists start_indexes and stop_indexes which contain respectively the start index to remove from and the end index to remove to. Then you can merge the two lists with the 'zip' method to have a matrix where each row has the start index and the end index of the rows to be removed. For each of these rows in the matrix you can create a list with the lines corresponding to the range of values and then remove the values contained in this list from the original list.

In this example the text to be processed divided into lines is stored in vals.

```py
vals = ['string', '#blabla', 'ciao', 'miao', 'bau', 'ENDOFPARAMETERPOINT', 'as']

start_indexes = []
stop_indexes = []

for index, line in enumerate(vals):
    if line[0] == '#':
        start_indexes.append(index)
    elif line == 'ENDOFPARAMETERPOINT':
        stop_indexes.append(index)

for start, stop in zip(start_indexes, stop_indexes):
    values_to_remove = [vals[x] for x in range(start, stop+1)]
    for v in values_to_remove:
        vals.remove(v)
```

Comment: Thanks Matteo. The fix was much easier but I appreciate your input.